# Matching lines with negative lookbehind for character string

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match lines that do not begin with "zzz_" using a negative lookbehind. Why doesn't what I have work?

```
(?<!(zzz_))\w+
```

https://regex101.com/r/kE7oC9/1

Comment: That's not a good case for lookbehind!

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to do it that way instead of, like, `[^(zzz_)]`?

Comment: @alfasin It doesn't matter, I'm just trying to understand the negative lookbehind.

Comment: @emodendroket: Because your proposition doesn't work at all ;(. What do you think `[^(zzz_)]` match.

Comment: @JESUISCHARLIE Hm.  Good reason.

Comment: @thomas that's not a good example for lookbehind, if you want to study it you should pursue it using better examples, for instance: match only lines in which any sequence of exactly 3 digits is not predecessed by the letter Y.

Answer (score 2):

Look aheads are something that you should be looking for

```
^(?!zzz_)\w+
```

- `^` Anchors the regex at the start of the string
- `(?!zzz_)` Negative look ahead. Checks if  the start is not followed by `zzz_` If it is not, then proceedss with the remaining pattern. else discards the string
- `\w+` matches `[a-zA-z0-9_]`

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/kE7oC9/2)

---

**Problem with `(?<!(zzz_))\w+`**

Lets take an example case on how it might match `zzz_asdf`

Now the regex matching is done from left to right starting from the first character

```
   zzz_asdf
  |
 (?<!zzz_asdf) At the begining the look behind is true since the string starting is not presceded by zzz_ Hence it proceeds with the rest of the pattern

   zzz_asdf
   |
  \w

   zzz_asdf
    |
    \w and so on till the end
```

---

If you still wants to try it look behinds, you can write something like

```
^....(?<!zzz_)\w+
```

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/kE7oC9/3)

Comment: Interesting. Thank you. Can you explain a bit how this works?

Comment: @thomas I have added an explanation. Hope it helps you :)

Comment: @alfasin Yeah its a look ahead.

Comment: Well, the title of the question asks for a lookbehind solution - not lookahead. And the solution you posted on the last line will not cover lines that have fewer than 4 characters!